# failed to load ldlinux.c32 on ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, 20.04, usb-installation

I am new to this installing the 20.04 LTS server version on my computer, I am unable to boot from my USB to install the OS, I tried a lot of USB boot creators for this but nothing seems to work.

Every time I try a new boot creator I get new errors like, "bootmgr is missing", "failed to load ldlinux.c32", "Booting Kernel failed: invalid argument". I am feeling very disappointed because if I cannot even create a boot drive following the instructions in this tutorial: [Create a bootable USB stick on Windows | Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#10-installation-complete).

I don't know what else to do from here on out.

Comment: How did you create the USB? Did you md5sum hashcheck the downloaded iso file, and did you media check it afterward?  Did you try the USB in a different USB port, and try it on another machine?

Comment: Did you write the correct architecture for your machine? or are you using a 32-bit only UEFI setup?  Is this on real hardware? or a cloud service?  (I see it also posted on https://news2.x-itm.com/failed-to-load-ldlinux-c32-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/ where it's listed in cloud)

Comment: @ubfan1 I used rufus to create the USB, and I checked the md5sum hashcheck its ok. I only have one machine to test this on.

Comment: @guiverc I am using this on a 64-bit, and this is on my desktop pc.

Comment: When I need to make an Ubuntu USB from Windows, I use: https://www.linuxliveusb.com/ It has never failed me. Have you tried a desktop version to see if that boots? and make sure you get your ISOs from here: https://ubuntu.com/#download

Comment: @MarkKirby I tried it too it doesn't seem to work too, now it says booting kernel failed invalid argument.

Comment: Do you have an option in your bios called secure boot? If so disable it and in windows disable fast boot https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213195423-How-To-Disable-Fast-Startup-in-Windows-10 both are known to cause issues, not sure it will fix it, but it won't hurt to try.

Comment: I am trying to install the OS in a new hard disk for my desktop @MarkKirby

Comment: Ok but still try disabling secure boot from your bios, it is known to cause issues. Some times when you buy a Windows PC or some mother boards secure boot will only accept Microsoft signed boot loaders.

Comment: ok let me try to find it out and do it @MarkKirby

Comment: I tried everything I could nothing seamed to work, at the end searched the net thoroughly about my explicit problems; nothing panned out, so reached a certain point and just gave up on it. @MarkKirby

Comment: I also read an article that the problems might occur due to having very old hardware, my hardware is about 9 years old; I think this is the problem why.

Comment: Well what do you know the .iso file is absolutely fine, I tried to run it on virtual machine and it runs without any problems what so ever. The answer to all the problems was that if you have very old hardware just throw it out the window or maybe blow it sky high.